# Error when using sql command "OVER PARTITION" using pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I was trying to learn SQL `over partition` command using sqlite3 and pandas.

Here is the database and the query:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create db if does not exist
con = sqlite3.connect("student.db")

data = [ ('Jolly', 'Female', 20, 500), 
('Jon', 'Male', 22, 545), 
('Sara', 'Female', 25, 600), 
('Laura', 'Female', 18, 400), 
('Alan', 'Male', 20, 500), 
('Kate', 'Female', 22, 500), 
('Joseph', 'Male', 18, 643), 
('Mice', 'Male', 23, 543), 
('Wise', 'Male', 21, 499), 
('Elis', 'Female', 27, 400)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','gender','age','total_score'])
df['id'] = range(len(df))
df_copy = df.copy()


# load df to database
df.to_sql("student", con, if_exists='replace',index=False)


# join
# This method is memory inefficient
q = """ SELECT id, name, 
Aggregation.gender, Aggregation.Total_students, 
Aggregation.Average_Age, Aggregation.Total_Score
FROM student
INNER JOIN
(SELECT gender, count(gender) AS Total_students, AVG(age) AS Average_Age, SUM(total_score) AS Total_Score
FROM student
GROUP BY gender) AS Aggregation
on Aggregation.gender = student.gender
"""

display(pd.read_sql_query(q,con))
```

I get the output like this:
[image]

Now, when I try to do the same command using OVER PARTITION, I got OperationalError: near "(": syntax error.

The code that produces the errors is the following:

```
# over partition
q3 = """ SELECT id, name, gender,
COUNT(gender) OVER (PARTITION BY gender) AS Total_students,
AVG(age) OVER (PARTITION BY gender) AS Average_Age,
SUM(total_score) OVER (PARTITION BY gender) AS Total_Score
FROM student
"""
pd.read_sql_query(q3,con)
```

How can the problem be solved?

Comment: Try and run this query on the database first. Check if it runs there properly.

Comment: Sqlite 3.25 introduced support for windows functions. If you're not working with this version then you can not use the OVER clause.

Comment: Why are you dumping your data into database, running SQL, then importing the resultset? Your desired output can be handled easily in pandas.